# Cell(J) vs Cof(J) in $\text{sSet}_{\text{Quillen}}$

Tags: homotopy-theory, simplicial-stuff, model-categories

consider sSet equipped with its Quillen model structure $\text{sSet}_{\text{Quillen}}$, we know that a trivial cofibration is a retract of a transfinite composition of pushouts of horn inclusions. I wonder if we can cancel the retraction without enlarging the set of generators (i.e. the horn inclusions). In other words I suspect that any trivial cofibration is actually a transfinite composition of pushouts of horn inclusions. Can someone shed some light on this "conjecture" ?

Thanks

Comment: Thus is true for cofibrations, but not for acyclic cofibrations.

Comment: @Dmitri: yes thanks, I know this is true for cofibrations (see Hovey (1999) 3.2.2) but do you have a reference for the case of acyclic cofibrations or can you elaborate on it ?

Comment: This is somewhere in Emily Riehl's papers on algebraic model categories, the distinction between cellular maps and retracts of cellular maps is very important in this context.